# Which one is better from JSON operations vs MySQL queries for better efficiency and less server load?

Tags: mysql, json, database

First of all, I know they are completely different things and cannot be compared directly but let me explain my question. I want to store polls as well as votes for the poll in which users can select from **Upvote** or **Downvote** only. I want to record each and every action which means I have to store more data in the database.

In this case, I have two options. Either I can make two tables named `faq` and `faq_votes` with following structure:

**Method 1:**

> faq table columns:`id` , `question(string)` , `answer(text)`, `created_at(timestamp)` and `updated_at(timestamp)`
>
> faq_votes table columns: `id` , `faq_id(foreign)` , `user_id(foreign)` and `vote(boolean)`

Or I can store everything in one table and I just have to add two columns in `faq` table. But in this case, I have to store votes in `JSON` format.

**Method 2:**

> faq table columns: `id` , `question(string)` , `answer(text)` , `upvotes(JSON)`, `downvotes(JSON)`, `created_at` and `updated_at`
>
> Example JSON: `{ "total": 5, "users":[ 3,6,10,12,2 ] }`

*In the first case*, I would fire lots and lots of MySQL queries to get my thing done. *And in the second case*, I would fire less amount of queries but I'll have to fire lots of JSON operations.

So, which option is better for more efficiency and less server load when we are talking about thousands of more operations on monthly basis?

Comment: Why would you need more queries for method 1? Using a stored procedure, you could pass all the data to MySQL with one roundtrip.

Comment: Why do you think there will be a different number of queries in the two cases?

Comment: You can insert multiple rows in a single query `INSERT INTO faq_votes VALUES (null, 1, 1), (null, 1, 2), (null, 1, 3)`

Comment: And retrieving the data from both tables is done with joins, not multiple queries.

Comment: Even though MySQL now has built-in JSON functions, sometimes it's really complicated to do some things that are easy to do with ordinary joins. I'm not convinced that it's very useful.

Comment: What I mean is, which one is better for my little server. I know there are thousands of way to get things done but I am confused from these two options. I want less load on server and better efficiency.

Comment: @AdarshSojitra It's hard to know the result for a specific application without benchmarking. I suspect it won't be too much different for what you're doing, so the real difference will be in complexity of application design.

Comment: @barmar , yes, it makes sense. It's just a module in which I have to record users votes for frequently asked questions and it's answers. Whether they liked it or not. And I don't want them to vote multiple times, so, I have to record activity too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second alternative (in which you store the user ids of voters in a JSON object) is **far far worse** than your first alternative.

Why? It won't scale up. To record the casting of, say, the 50,000th vote on an item, you'll have to read a large JSON object, modify it, and overwrite it in the database with an UPDATE operation.  That will take a long time.

What about the situation where the 80,000th voter changes her vote from up to down? How complex an operation will it be to do that.

In your first alternative, each new vote requires simply an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` operation, and simply puts a new row into the votes table.   SQL is made to do things this way.

**Edit** Think of this problem this way:

- two entities: user and faq.
- one relationship between user and faq: a vote.

Your entity tables will have `user_id` and `faq_id` unique identifiers, and whatever other columns your application requires.

Your relationship table, call it `vote`, will have one row for each vote. It relates `user_id` to `faq_id`.  This relationship table needs three columns.

```
user_id     PK   FK to user.user_id
faq_id      PK   FK to faq.faq_id
vote        TINYINT   1  or -1
datestamp   TIMESTAMP   the time of casting the vote.
```

Notice that the `vote` table has a compound primary key. This serves to prevent a user from voting more than once for a faq.

A structure like this gives you very flexible reporting. For example, this query will find the most-upvoted FAQ in the past two days.

```
 SELECT v.faq_id, SUM(v.vote) votes
   FROM vote v 
  WHERE v.datestamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
  GROUP BY v.faq_id
  ORDER BY SUM(v.vote) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

This example gives you the user who cast the most downvotes in the past week

```
 SELECT v.user_id, u.user_name, COUNT(*) downvotes
   FROM vote v
   JOIN user u ON v.user_id = u.user_id
  WHERE v.vote < 0 
    AND v.datestamp >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
  GROUP BY v.user_id, u.user_name
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: But yes, according to you, what kind of structure will be good in this case .